# Evaluate $\int \frac{1}{1+x}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I forgot about integrals so I need some help in this problem $\displaystyle\int \frac{1}{1+x}\, dx$ please.

Comment: Do you know what $\int \frac {dx}x$ evaluates to?

Comment: It equals $\;\log|1+x|+C\;$ whenever it is well-defined

Comment: log to the base e or to the base 10 or something other?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=integrate+1%2F(1%2Bx)+dx

Comment: @DonAntonio Do you mean $\ln|1+x|$?

Comment: @JChau: one of the default meanings of $\log(x)$ is $\log_e(x)=\ln(x)$, and it is often a matter of personal preference which one is written down..

Comment: @abiessu Thanks for clarifying I didn't know that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the $u$-substitution $u=1+x$ then $\mathrm du=\mathrm dx$ so the integral becomes $$\int\dfrac1u\,\mathrm du.$$

Comment: @user145223 You're welcome! $\overset{\cdot\cdot}\smile$

Answer (score 3):

Your integral:
$$\int \frac{1}{1+x} \ \text dx$$
Use the u-substitution $u=1+x$. Then $\text du = \text dx$
$$\int \frac 1u \ \text du$$
The integral of $\frac{1}{u}$ is $\ln|u| + C$
$$\int \frac 1u \ du = \ln|u| + C$$
Reverse the substitution.
$$\color{green}{\int \frac{1}{1+x} \ \text dx=\ln\left|1+x \right|+C}$$
Hope I helped!

Comment: thanks but i needed only a hint! thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

A primitive is log|1+x|, because of the rule that a primitive of u'/u is ln|u|.

Because this solution is not defined in at the point x=-1, the general solution is 
log(1+x) + C_1 when x > -1 and log(-(1+x)) + C_2 when x < -1.

Comment: Some one help with the formatting

Comment: Here (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial. Read it carefully - once you pass a certain reputation mark, the site consensus is that you should be experienced enough to type basic MathJax.